# How to add fade css styling and image to every switch statement change

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement

The basis of the app is to show users the possible result of their donations to a charity. e.g. when you input $10 it will display "provide clothes for starving children"

I want to add some styling by fading in the end result display which only happens once, if I change the input to another number to create a new text string in id="text-result", it does not fade, only switches without animation.

And I want to be able to include different images with changing switch statements.

Many thanks.

HTML

```
<p> If you donate <input type="text" id="donation" value"3" onchange="imag()"> </input> you could provide <a id="text-result"></a></p>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

#text-result {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

JS:

```
function imag() {
  var x = document.getElementById("donation").value;
  var text;
  var picture;

  switch (true) {
    case x <= 10:
      text = "clothes to starving children";
      break;
    case x > 10:
      text = "clothes to adults";
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("text-result").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("text-result").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

codepen is here: https://codepen.io/keifreelancing/pen/ExagzxP

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fade back in because after the first entry, opacity is set to 1 and stays there unless told otherwise. You'd need to reduce the opacity for it to fade back in. Off the top of my head, a `setTimeout()` function can do the trick. See fork here: https://codepen.io/Klammyq/pen/xxbENQX.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you have any idea on adding an image to the switch?